# How to match with two fields without foreign key relation using models in django

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I have three tables like models. In this three models have no foreign key relation, Options are table1 and table2 have relation, table3 there is no foreign key compared with table1 and table2 three different tables,I need to match the values and get the results.How do i make ORM query with maching the columns.

In SQL:

```
select a.*,b.*,c.* from table1 a,table2 b,table3 c where a.country = b.country and a.log = c.port;
```

I trying to ORM:

```
Tables1.objects.filter(Q(country = F('tables2__country')) & Q(log = F('table3__port'))).values('AAA','BBB','CCC')
```

But it's not working i got error:

> "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))..etc..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use `F` expression for another table,
but maybe this works:

```
table2_countries = table2.objects.all().values_list("country")
table3_logs = table3.objects.all().values_list("port")
Tables1.objects.filter(country__in=table2_countries, log__in=table3_logs))
```